# What is the pro-algebraic completion of the free semigroup on one generator?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, ag.algebraic-geometry

This question is motivated by an attempt to understand what is going on in Tom's [post](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/12/the_eventual_image.html#more) from a certain point of view.

Let $\mathbb N^+$ be the free semigroup on one generator (so the positive natural numbers with addition).  Is it true that the underlying semigroup of the pro-algebraic completion of $\mathbb N^+$ can be described as $\mathbb N^+\sqcup G$ where $G$ is the pro-algebraic completion of the additive group of integers, where adding an element of $\mathbb N^+$ to an element of $G$ is done by first identifying an element of $\mathbb N^+$ with its copy in $\mathbb Z\subseteq G$?

Assume the ground field is algebraically closed if you like.

Remark: If you replace pro-algebraic by profinite, then it is true.

Comment: Also the analogue for free monogenic compact semigroups is true. 

Comment: I have made a very small style edit --- if I have trod on your style, I apologize, and you should rever the edit. I notices that there was unneeded TeX in the title, which slows load times for some users, so I removed that, and in the process I made a similar change in the body.

Comment: (Incidentally, "rever" = "reverse", of course, and apparently I hit a keyboard neighbor when I meant to hit a "d", among other typos in my previous comment.)

Comment: Could you give a link to a definition of the pro-algebraic completeion of a semigroup (or give a definition yourself)?  I'm having trouble finding it.  Thanks.

Comment: The definition has only been made for groups on the literature but makes sense for semigroups. A pro-algebraic semigroup is a projective limit of (linear) algebraic semigroups. The pro-algebraic completion is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor from pro-algebraic semigroups to semigroups. 